# How to quick and easy remove part of an URL in Nginx with HttpRewriteModule?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, redirection

I know about the [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule), but I don't really know how to handle regex and I would need to redirect all URLs within a certain directory to another, specifically:

From: `example.com/component/tag/whatever`

To: `example.com/tag/whatever`

Could some one tell me how to do this in Nginx?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
rewrite ^/component(.*)$ $1 last;
```

Comment: I think this will do it, thank you so much. I'm awful at regular expressions; I will have to try to learn them...

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/qJ5gU1/1 has explanation on the right side

Comment: You may need to replace last by break. (Last will try to resolve other locations after the rewrite).

Comment: It only worked for me with `break` and not with `last`.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux  what is the difference between break and last

Comment: `last` = stop rewriting this request and search for a new matching `location` block, and `break` = stop rewriting this request and continue execution within the current `location` block

Answer (score 4):

Depending where you define the `rewrite` directive you have two ways to implement it:

#### A. In the `server` context

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/component(.*)$ $1 last;
    ...
}
```

#### B. In the `location` context

```
location /component {
    rewrite ^/component(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

**Teo, why did you change the flag `last` to `break`?** Because, if this directive is put inside of a `location` context, the `last` flag will make `nginx` to run 10 cycles and return the 500 error.